# Variable can't been seen

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

sorry this may be a simple question. I am trying to build my first navigation using jQuery. The idea is that on hover of the button that the background colour and text colour changes as long as it is not the 'selected' button. I have all this working fine apart from the text colour. As in the jQuery it cannot see my loop variable:

```
function testIndex(navIndex){
        for(i=0; i<=4; i++){
            if(i != navIndex){
                $('#nav a:eq('+i+')').hover(function(){
                    $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.3, function(){
                        $(this).css('background-color','#ff3520');
                        $('#nav li:eq('+i+')').css('color', '#ffffff');
                    }).fadeTo('fast', 1);
                },
                function(){
                    $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.3, function(){
                        $(this).css('background-color', '#e8e8e8');
                        $('#nav li:eq('+i+')').css('color', '#ff3520');
                    }).fadeTo('fast', 1);
                });
            };  
        };
    };
```

On the

```
$('#nav li:eq('+i+')').css('color', '#ff3520');
```

The 'i' variable cannot be seen. I've tested it by inserting my own variables and it works.

Any advice?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "Cannot be seen"?

Comment: What if you change the `for` statement to `for(var i=0; i<=4; i++)`?

Comment: Add `var` in front of `i` otherwise you'll only get the last value, as your variable is global

Comment: The variable can not be seen. Sounds like a job for H.P. Lovecraft.

Comment: @jli As in cannot be used by the $('#nav li:eq('+i+')').css('color', '#ff3520'); section. However, it can be used by $('#nav a:eq('+i+')').hover(function()...

Comment: @RichardEv I have just given this a go and still nothing?

Comment: @nico and Richard Ev: That will not work in JavaScript.

Comment: Please have a lok at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example. But there is likely a better solution for your problem, please post an example of your HTML structure.

Comment: @user1600680: why? It generally works for me in cases like yours...

Comment: @nico: Not in JavaScript. There is no block scope, so there is only one `i` variable scoped to the function, which means it is overwritten in the loop. Since all the handlers made in the loop are referring to the same `i` variable, they will all get the value it was left at after the loop completed.

Comment: @nico: Here is a demo with the for loop. http://jsfiddle.net/PQYNE/ and here is one with `i` scoped in a function. http://jsfiddle.net/PQYNE/1/

Comment: @user1600680: weird, I am pretty sure I had some situation like that, which I solved by just adding `var`. Evidently the situation was not *exactly* like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are in a loop, need a variable scope to keep reference to `i` in the handler.

```
function testIndex(navIndex){
    $.each(Array(5), function(i) {
        if(i != navIndex){
            $('#nav a:eq('+i+')').hover(function(){
                $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.3, function(){
                    $(this).css('background-color','#ff3520');
                    $('#nav li:eq('+i+')').css('color', '#ffffff');
                }).fadeTo('fast', 1);
            },
            function(){
                $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.3, function(){
                    $(this).css('background-color', '#e8e8e8');
                    $('#nav li:eq('+i+')').css('color', '#ff3520');
                }).fadeTo('fast', 1);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

In JavaScript calling a function makes a variable scope, so I used `$.each` for the loop, because it calls the function for each array index.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you, I thought it was a scope problem but I complicated things for myself I think.

Answer (score 1):

It has already been explained what the problem with your code is (scope of `i`) and solutions have been provided. Also have a look at this related question: [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example).

However you can solve it differently, not using an index at all but using DOM traversal, in a more jQuery-oriented way. I assume your HTML looks similar to this:

```
<ul id="#nav">
    <li><a>...</a></li>
    <li><a>...</a></li>
</ul>
```

i.e. the `a` elements are descendants of the `li` you want to change.

You can then achieve the same with the following code:

```
function testIndex(navIndex){
    $('#nav a').slice(0,5).not(function(i) { 
        return i === navIndex;
    }).hover(function(){
        $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.3, function(){
            $(this).css('background-color','#ff3520')
              .closest('li').css('color', '#ffffff');
         }).fadeTo('fast', 1);
    }, function(){
        $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.3, function(){
            $(this).css('background-color', '#e8e8e8');
              .closest('li').css('color', '#ff3520');
        }).fadeTo('fast', 1);
    });
}
```